# PHP printf linebreak

Tags: php, printf

I have the following printf statement:

```
   printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["word"], $row["definition"]);
```

I'm trying to resolve a line break where it instead of:

```
 word definition
```

I want as output:

```
word
definition
```

I have tried  `< /br >` `/n/r` etc and it produces either a warning or just the word without the definition.

Thankyou

Comment: The < br> wont work :/

Comment: Output is... file? Or what? 
Try PHP_EOL

Comment: Output is printed text on a website.

Comment: I just tested this with \n works fine. Outputs a linebreak to the source code. Note that a \n will not be visible as a linebreak when viewed as a web page.

Comment: `echo "word".PHP_EOL."definition";` if it is text or `echo "word<br />definition";` if it is html

Comment: @MerlinDenker I think I might be inserting the \n in the wrong location.  Where are you inserting it?

Comment: It's not clear whether you have issues with Stack Overflow formatting or you're really using `< /br>` and `/n/r`, which are of course completely invalid. It's also not clear yet whether you want HTML or plain text.

Comment: printf("%s\n(%s)", "word", "definition");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `\n` in between the two words rather than at the end of the string.

```
printf ("%s\n(%s)",$row["word"], $row["definition"]);
```

In case you're outputting to HTML/Browser you might want to entirely replace your `\n` with `<br />`:

```
printf ("%s<br />(%s)",$row["word"], $row["definition"]);
```

Comment: @user3220585 Doing it wrong? Double check your code!

Comment: @user3220585 - Read the error message. It's faster than guessing.

Comment: @user3220585 What *happened* to the server?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want a line break and no `<br/>` tag (as you told) then you are encouraged to use `PHP_EOL` as it contains the line break character based on the current system:

```
echo "word" . PHP_EOL . "definition";
```

Btw, `printf()` isn't required here.

However, if the text that is outputted is visited on a different system than the server, for example Linux server and Windows Client, then you need to use the [line break character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_character) of the target system. For Windows this is `\r\n`

Comment: This produces word and definition on the same line

Comment: How do you debug this? in browser?

Comment: Yes, debug in browser

Answer (score 0):

you can just use echo with br tag

```
echo $row["word"] . "<br />" . $row["definition"];
```